# How do I do substitution against just part of a larger pattern?

Tags: regular-expression

I have a string like `18NTC101L` , which I can search by `\v[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}L`.
Now, I just want to replace the `L` at the end with letter `T`.

How I can do that?

Comment: One way: use `\zs` and `\ze` in your pattern to surround `L` then `:%s/{pattern}/T/`.

Comment: `\d` instead of `[0-9]` and `\u` (or maybe `\U`) instead of `[A-Z]` should work too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### use \zs

`:h \zs` sets the start of the search, meaning that the next char is the first one of the whole match. So in the end you specify only `T` to replace with.

```
%s/\v[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}\zsL/T/
```

### use grouping () together with \1

`:h \1` and `:h \(\)`

```
%s/\v([0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3})L/\1T/
```

Group everything till `L` and replace with what was matched in a group `\1` and `T`

Probably more options are available...